# brakes aren't releasing after replacing my brake switch and lamp failure module

Tags: brakes

I just replaced my brake pedal switch and my lamp failure module. It drove fine for a mile or so and now for some reason my brakes are grabbing and not releasing.It's almost like the parking brake is engaged, but it's not. HElP!!!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What are you working on? The year/make/model/engine would be a great start! :o)

Comment: Does your brake pedal sit lower than usual before you press it? The new switch/module could be preventing the brake pedal from rising fully..Look at the switch while moving the pedal with your hand.